# How long to -reindex -dbcache=2048 with txindex = 1?

Tags: reindex

i have fullnode with lastest block 130GB.
I want txindex=1 and i need run with -reindex and -dbcache=2048 for speed reindex.
How long duration of process ?
My server is jelastic 10/250, now 18 MHz.
I can make new address and send bitcoin in proccess of reindex?

Answer (score 0):

> I can make new address and send bitcoin in proccess of reindex?

Yes, but your wallet won't be able to check whether it has been confirmed by the network (i.e. mined) until it is caught up and synced with the block in which said transaction was mined.